# Cannot resolve symbol when inserting data

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, h2, slick-3.0

im following this tutorial, http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/gettingstarted.html#populating-the-database. When i copy that code it says 'cannot resolve symbol...'
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVl2H.png)

im using IntelliJ

app/controllers/tables.scala:

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import slick.lifted.{ProvenShape, ForeignKeyQuery}


class Suppliers(tag: Tag)
extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {

def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey)
def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
def street: Rep[String] = column[String]("STREET")
def city: Rep[String] = column[String]("CITY")
def state: Rep[String] = column[String]("STATE")
def zip: Rep[String] = column[String]("ZIP")

def * : ProvenShape[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)] =
  (id, name, street, city, state, zip)
}

class Coffees(tag: Tag)
extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {

def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
def supID: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
def price: Rep[Double] = column[Double]("PRICE")
def sales: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("SALES")
def total: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("TOTAL")

def * : ProvenShape[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)] =
  (name, supID, price, sales, total)

def supplier: ForeignKeyQuery[Suppliers, (Int, String, String, String, String, String)] =
  foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, TableQuery[Suppliers])(_.id)
}
```

application.conf:

```
h2mem1 = {
url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test"
driver = org.h2.Driver
connectionPool = disabled
keepAliveConnection = true
}
// im using jdbc:h2:~/test as my URL in H2 Console(port 8082)
// currently using Generic H2 (Embedded)
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
db.default.username=sa
db.default.password=""
```

build:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 jdbc,
 cache,
 ws,
 specs2 % Test,
 "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.0",
 "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.190",
 "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
 "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.1.0"
)
libraryDependencies += evolutions
```

Im using the IntelliJ IDE, got all the plugins i need: play, scala etc. Am I missing something else? or is it my code

Comment: How are you building your code? In the sbt terminal or in Intellij? (sorry if that's obvious from the tutorial, I've not seen it before)

Comment: For the future, please include the precise error. It doesn't just say 'cannot resolve symbol...': what symbol? On what line?

Comment: the errors occur on the red words: Suppliers, Coffees and run(check image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't resolve `suppliers` and `coffees`, at least, because you missed their definitions:

```
val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers]

val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
```

Comment: i did put those two lines of code in class Database, and i still get those errors.

`class Database {
val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers]
val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]

val Setup = DBIO.seq(
// Create the tables, including primary and foreign keys`